# PHP lstat command doesn't distinguish shortcuts in windows

Tags: php, mode, stat, readdir

In windows, I open a dir, read the files, and for each file, run stat to determine the size, etc.

The problem is that when I run stat on a folder SHORTCUT, it comes back as a FOLDER, and I can't see anywhere in the `mode` bitmask that might indicate this. This has been true for all of the folder shortcuts in `c:\Documents and Settings\myUserName\`.

For these shortcuts, `is_file` returns `false`, `is_dir` returns `true` and `is_link` isn't supported in XP.

Here's an excerpt from my code (it has been trimmed down, so there may be bugs) :

```
if(($h=@opendir($root))!==false){
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($h))){
        if(!($file=="." || $file=="..")){
            if( $stat = @lstat($root . $file) ){
                $ary[0] = $file;
                $ary[1] = $root;
                $ary[2] = Date("m/d/y H:i:s", $stat['mtime']);
                if($stat['mode'] & 040000){
                    $ary[3]="dir";
                    $ary[4]=0;
                }else{
                    $ary[3] ="file";
                    $ary[4] = $stat['size'];
                }
                echo(json_encode($ary));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A workaround for this will be appreciated...

**EDIT: Winterblood's solution almost worked**

First off - my bad - it's a win7 machine.

Thanks Winterblood for the quick turnaround - this worked for several of the shortcuts, and the PHP manual says just that... However,

c:\users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Application Data

(and others) are still coming back as directories, while winSCP correctly sees them as shortcuts. As a matter of fact, the 'mode' is 040777, which is exactly the same as many real folders.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `stat()` function "follows" shortcuts/symlinks, reporting details on the linked file/folder, not the actual link itself.

For getting stat details on the link itself use `lstat()`.

More information in [the PHP documentation on lstat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lstat.php).

Comment: Hot damn - I typed a little-ol' 'l' into my code and heard the bells of angels.

Comment: Almost made it... I adjusted my original post to reflect the current situation.

Comment: As far as I knew %LocalAppData% was a real folder. If lstat is reporting it is a real folder but WinSCP is reporting it as a link I'd be more questioning of the software, not the language.

Comment: thanks for the insight - you're right... In fact, when I right-click c:\users\me\Local Settings\Application Data (which has the shortcut overlay on the icon, it reports as a real file folder rather than a shortcut. However, it does, in fact, link to itself, and when I open it, and continue opening it in the subfolder, eventually my path looks like this: c:\users\me\Local Settings\Application Data\Application Data\. WinSCP doesn't do this - it simply stays at the original folder. My goal is to find out how to replicate this for nested readdir(). Might is_link() help with this?

Comment: OK, I've had a quick look into it. C:\Users\username\Local Settings was the place for local data on WinXP. In Win7 they updated this to instead be C:\Users\username\AppData\Local. For backwards compatibility the old local settings path exists as a [junction point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968829(VS.85).aspx). Junction points are not meant to be user accessible - check the link for more info including how to identify them.

Comment: Well, between all of the hard work that @winterblood did and the assumptions I am making, here is the (assumed) answer:

The folders in question (the ones I don't want to recurse, because they are "junction points") have lstat['mode'] & 040006. That's it. If lstat['mode'] & 040006, then don't follow it.

winterblood, many thanks for your hard work. You are certainly an asset to this planet.

Comment: Glad to help. I'm always happy to see my assistance put to use, and there is always the possibility that what we've learned here will help me in the future, too.